# backbone.js pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, backbone.js

I am beginning to use Backbone and am trying to transition my Rails backend's html templates to javascript templates.

One thing I thought using backbone would be more advantageous is its concept of Models and Collections.
So say, I have 100 records and am paginating these records to 10 per page, normally, without quite a bit of javascript work, one can hardly expect a *cached*, *ajax*, *one-page* pagination experience. meaning, say, I landed on page one and now click page two, page two requests the next 10 records ajax'ly, and if I then click page one, I won't be making any more request to the server because it was there.

I haven't had any code written up but can anyone tell me how I can append the ajax requested newly arrived data to the existing collection for pagination?

For instance, remember Backbone's documentation say that your first load of the page should really contain bootstrapped data instead of making a second trip to fetch them. So

```
var projects_data = <%= @projects.to_json.html_safe %>;
var projects = new Cafe.Collections.ProjectsCollection();
var projects.reset(projects_data);
```

Now my projects variable contains, say, the first 10 records, and I someone retreive another round of 10, say, I save these newly arrived 10 in the variable

```
var projects_data_new = ...
```

Can I append them to the existing "projects" collection?

Or is this not the design pattern encouraged in Backbone in the case of pagination?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In backbone 0.5 and up, when you call `fetch()`, it is possible to specify that you wish to add rather than replace the dataset present on the client: `fetch({add: true})`.  This will append new objects to the existing `projects` collection.  You will still have to handle pagination presentation issues on your end.

The collection also only gets the JSON objects to add/fetch after they have been run through `Backbone.Collection.parse()`, which you can override to do things like "along with the projects, give me a count of all objects on the server, and return only the projects to the add/fetch."  You can then use this metadata to correctly show how many pages the user *can* page through.  If you want to be really clever, you can use the collection as a sparse array (my experience is that this is fine for collections of less than 10,000 items on a standard desktop or laptop, but not a tablet), and let the user flip through the pages arbitrarily, fetching the filler as needed.

Comment: Thanks Elf, the "clever" approach sounds really interesting(!), can I ask you what a "sparse array" mean?

Comment: A sparse array is one where not every object is present; you might have objects 1-10, 40-50, and 90-100 for example, if you had a pagination of "10 items per page."  This means that every object in your collection needs not only itself but its position in the (abstract or server-side) collection, and rather than merely position your index and spew out the next ten, you'd have to filter the collection, determine if the objects were present, fetch them if they were not, and repeat the filter process to show them.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for writing all this.

Answer (score 10):

Hope you have tackled the problem by now :) 
As [Elf Sternberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166838/elf-sternberg) pointed out, the magic is in defining your Collection's parse() which is further explained by the link below:

[first whack at pagination with backbone.js](https://gist.github.com/705733)

For example how to write parse:

> // Supposing we send an object like {page: 1, per_page: 3, total: 233,
>   models: {...} }

```
parse: function(resp) {
    this.page = resp.page;
    this.perPage = resp.per_page;
    this.total = resp.total;
    return resp.models;
  }
```

Once you have these details in your Collection, you just have to tailor your views accordingly, which I am sure won't be that hard given that you are already this Far :)

Comment: Wow that gist is almost a year old! He is *advanced*! I haven't finished the entire transition from erb partials and templates to Backbone+underscore templates. But it is more than "on the radar", as I see it, it's a must because, well, purely, of speed and being easier on the server ( goal was to bypass rails stack for the JSON, as I am already using MongoDB, which by default churns out JSON). Thanks so much for your follow-ups here. Will indeed put out my version of some gists of how I do it to give back.

Comment: Yes, I was also amazed that I was using an year old Gist last night :D I just searched for pagination in backbone.js on Google and that came out as first.

It really helped alot and I'm glad to help you :)

Comment: Ha, you just came back a month later to laugh at it :) He is advance

Comment: Someone upvoted this answer so I reread your comment, I do that sometimes :P

Comment: I've spent a couple of days slightly improving on this gist and released it as a [GitHub project](https://github.com/GeReV/Backbone.PagedCollection). Also supports some basic caching of pages. Hope this helps.